# Template implementation for Html.ValidationMessageFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, editortemplates

I want to define HTML structure for Html.ValidationMessageFor in a View. This should be similar to EditorTemplates. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

> How can this be done?

It can't be done. You will have to write a custom ValidationMessageFor helper. The generated HTML is not extensible and is hardcoded in the built-in helper. You may download the [ASP.NET MVC 3 source code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781) and see how the default helper is implemented. This could be used as a starting point for writing your custom helper that will generate the desired markup.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about implementing custom helper. But how can my custom helper use View to render its output. The main goal is to not have any html structure hard coded in the helper.

Comment: @mishkovski, inside your custom helper you could use the Html.RenderPartial method to call a custom partial or something.

Answer (score 0):

The view can use the custom HtmlHelper method by adding a reference to the method's namespace.

My view, after using @Darin Dimitrov's guidance, looks similar to the following code:

```
@model Project.Models.MyModel
@using Project.Helper;
...
@Html.ValidationMessageFor_ThatYouMade(model => model.PropertyBeingValidated)
```

Comment: Is this a solution or not? If yes, you can remove the introductory remark. If not, please refrain from posting comments as answers, if you do it X number of times you'll be banned from posting answers...